# CUDA versions not the same

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, cuda

I have installed CUDA 10.1 on my Ubuntu 18.04 workstation which I can find in the `/usr/local` folder but when I run `nvidia-smi` I get it to be version 11.2 and when I run `nvcc --version` I get version 9.1 and in the `~/.bashrc` file I have these

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64"
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/cuda/bin"
```

so I am confused not sure how the three are different?

[image]

Comment: Possible:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53422407/different-cuda-versions-shown-by-nvcc-and-nvidia-smi

Comment: The above link explains everything. In addition, you did not follow instructions to put your cuda bin and lib64 first in your PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  Find which nvcc you are running (which nvcc) -- it's probably not from your 10.1 bin dir.

Comment: @ubfan1 what do you mean by "you did not follow instructions to put your cuda bin and lib64 first in your PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH" and the nvcc gives 9.1 how I can make it gets the 10.1 I installed?

Comment: You added your cuda locations to the end of the existing PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH, instead of putting them at the start. At the start of the list, the 10.1/bin will be scanned first (for nvcc) and your version from the 10.1/bin should be 10.1.